# Cinnamon input language change on UP key event

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I have Intellij IDEA installed on my Debian Jessie with Cinnamon. It has shortcut <kbd>ALT+SHIFT+F10</kbd>. The problem is that the input language change shortcut is <kbd>ALT+SHIFT</kbd>, so when I try to use IntelliJ shortcut it works, but it also changes the language.

Moreover, on my work computer under Windows 10, the language doesn't change. I think it is because, on Windows, language switching is performed after I release the keys, and on Debian when keys are pressed.

So how should I set language change shortcut on `keyUp` event? Again, my goal is to use IntelliJ <kbd>ALT+SHIFT+F10</kbd> shortcut without immediate language switching (assigned to <kbd>ALT+SHIFT</kbd>).

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts on Cinnamon are changed in the Keyboard Settings Screen. To begin editing shortcuts click on the menu button, navigate to preferences and scroll down until you see "Keyboard".

[image]

Note, on my system I do not have anything mapped to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> so you might have another application that is listening on that key combination.